# Zonal statistic that fits area portion of polygons using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

As you can see below, I have a polygon feature with boundary of seven regions. I need to extract the raster value intersect to it that fit portion of every region area touches to the pixel. For example, region 4 touches some % area of pixel f and the rest % area of pixel g.

So the final results value I want for region 4 is equal to (% area of pixel f **x** raster value of pixel f) + (% area of pixel g **x** raster value of pixel g).

I'm using ArcMap.

[image]

Comment: @Vince i have done a zonal stats process, but it only extracts region 4 and 5 where they both touch the pixel centroid (usual zonal statistic). and it extracts entire value of pixel f (to region 4) and g (to region 5), although not all of the regions is inside these pixel.

Comment: @PolyGeo i've decided to use ArcMap

Comment: I edited your question to make that choice clear.

Answer (score 1):

I would convert your raster into a polygon dataset and then use the Union tool with the boundaries and this dataset, this will allow you to answer the question of proportion of overlap.